Water Intrusion into Crawlspace
I recently crawled all the way around my crawlspace for the first time in years just to inspect everything. Most things looked like they were in good shape, however I did find one area of concern near where the back door and the deck are:

It looks like there is some wood rot on the exterior of the door and the seal plate is not going all the way into the deck, causing the slight gap seen in the first photo:

I am looking for ways to fix this myself if it is feasible. Would a good temporary fix be to take waterproof tape and liberally apply it to all areas of the exterior including the rotting wood? And is the rest of the fix something that I can do myself, and if so what would be the best approach to going about it myself? I'd like to prevent further intrusion and potentially replace/fix that area of wood seen from the crawlspace.
